# Calculate points to create a curve or spline to draw an ellipse

Tags: c#, algorithm, graphics, dundas

I am working with Dundas maps and need to overlay the map with bubbles depicting some data. I want to add shapes to the map in order to achieve this. I can add a triangle (or any straight-line-polygon) like this:

```
public static void AddShape(this MapControl map, List<MapPoint> points, Color color, string name)
{
    if (points[0].X != points[points.Count - 1].X && points[0].Y != points[points.Count - 1].Y)
        points.Add(points[0]);
    var shape = new Shape
    {
        Name = name,
        BorderColor = color,
        BorderStyle = MapDashStyle.Solid,
        BorderWidth = 1,
        Color = Color.FromArgb((int)(255 * (0.3)), color)
    };
    var segments = new[] {new ShapeSegment {Type = SegmentType.Polygon, Length = points.Count}};
    shape.AddSegments(points.ToArray(), segments);
    map.Shapes.Add(shape);
}

public static void AddBermudaTriangle(this MapControl map)
{
    var points = new List<MapPoint>
                     {
                         new MapPoint(-80.15, 26.0667),
                         new MapPoint(-64.75, 32.333),
                         new MapPoint(-66.07, 18.41)
                     };
    map.AddShape(points, Color.Red, "Bermuda Triangle");
}
```

[image: Bermuda Triangle]

You can see that the Bermuda Triangle overlays the map in red. Now I want to calculate a set of points to pass to my AddShape method that would draw an elipse or circle. I just need a simple algorithm for calculating the x and y coordinates of a given number of points. Perhaps starting with a given point that would represent the centre of the circle. For example:

```
public static void AddCircle(this MapControl map, Point centre, double radius, string name)
{
    var points = new List<MapPoint>();
    const int n = 360;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //calculate x & y using n, radius and centre
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        points.Add(new MapPoint(x, y));
    }
    map.AddShape(points, Color.Red, name);
}
```

I know that the x,y calculation is simple trigonometry but I'm suffering a brain freeze. Help!

EDIT (Solved using tur!ng's code):

```
public static void AddCircle(this MapControl map, Color color, MapPoint centre, double radius, string name)
{
    var points = new List<MapPoint>();
    const int n = 360;
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var x = (radius * Math.Cos(i * Math.PI / 180)) + centre.X;
        var y = (radius * Math.Sin(i * Math.PI / 180)) + centre.Y;
        points.Add(new MapPoint(x, y));
    }
    map.AddShape(points, color, name);
}
```

[image]

The blue circle (over Greenwich) is distorted because of the map projection over a Robinson grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  double x = centre.x + radius*Math.cos(2*Math.PI/360 * i);
  double y = centre.y + radius*Math.sin(2*Math.PI/360 * i);
```

for a circle.

Answer (score 2):

Copied from an old C++ program I wrote a long time ago, it still runs at dozens of places:

```
  // Approximate arc with small line segments
  double sa = dp[ix].center.angle(dp[ix].co);
  double ea = dp[ix].center.angle(dp[ix+1].co);
  double r = scale * dp[ix].radius;
  double rot = ea - sa;
  double inc = rot;
  if (dp[ix].dir == ROTCW) rot = -rot;
  if (rot < 0) rot += 2*PI;
  // Compute rotation increment that generates less than 1/4 pixel error
  if (r > 2) inc = 2*acos(1-0.25/r);
  if (inc >= rot || r < 2) addPoint(x, y);
  else {
    int cnt = int(1 + rot / inc);
    inc = rot / cnt;
    if (dp[ix].dir == ROTCW) inc = -inc;
    for (int jx = 0; jx < cnt; ++jx) {
      x = offsx + scale * dp[ix].center.x + r * cos(sa);
      y = offsy + scale * dp[ix].center.y + r * sin(sa);
      addPoint(x, y);
      sa += inc;
    }
  }
```

acos() is the same as Math.Acos().

Comment: Thanks, the rotation increment is useful to me!

Comment: Hans, If you're still around, please would you mind explaining a few things in that code? What type is in the dp array? I'd guess an array of Geometries? What's it's "co" attribute? And what's the scale? I'd guess it's double, but of what sort of magnitude. I've got a compilable version of that ported to C#, but I'm still a long way from working code.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the formula for a circle may be expressed as

```
(x/r)**2 + (y/r)**2 = 1
```

where x and y are coordinates and r is radius.

The formula for an ellipse may be expressed as

```
(x/a)**2 + (y/b)**2 = 1
```

where a and b are the semimajor and semiminor axes (in no particular order).  Choose a and b to give you an ellipse that "looks good".

You usually want to pick your points around a circle at equal angular steps, to make a better looking polygonal approximation to a true circle.  For this, you use the substitutions

```
x = r cos theta
y = r sin theta
```

and run your loop for theta from zero to 2*pi.  For your ellipse, you'll use

```
x = a cos theta
y = b sin theta
```

This gives you an ellipse with the semimajor and semiminor axes parallel to the X and Y axes and centered at the origin.  If you want an arbitrary orientation, with an arbitrary position, you'll need to apply a rotation by an angle phi, and a translation.  Any good computer graphics text will give you the necessary equations, most likely in matrix form.

Comment: Thanks! I'm working on an elipse implementation now using your suggestions.